# Yii1 set the default value for DB column in migration

Tags: php, yii, migration

I support the Yii 1.1.14 application and I have to add the new column into my database table in migration file. I use the next:

```
$this->addColumn('table', 'columnName', 'varchar(100)');
```

How can I set the default value for this column? And, also, I want to place the column after the concrete one.

Or, maybe, should I use the another method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
$this->addColumn('table', 'columnName', "varchar(100) DEFAULT 'my default string'");
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. And what about placing column after concrete? $this->addColumn('table', 'columnName', "varchar(100) DEFAULT 'my default string' AFTER 'column2'");

Comment: Depends on the database you are using. For example MySQL supports keywords FIRST and AFTER. Note that column names must be un-quoted or quoted using backticks: `$this->addColumn('table', 'columnName', "varchar(100) DEFAULT 'my default string' AFTER column2");`